# Date on the bottom of the page without drafting option in ClassicThesis

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis` to write my document. I don't use the option `drafting` but I can see on the bottom of the page the date (there is a part of the date that is not readable, but when I copy and paste this part I obtain `[ December 1, 2011 at 20:50 ]`). This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}   % classe report di KOMA-Script

\usepackage[english]{babel}     % Per scrivere in inglese
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Imposta la codifica dei font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Lettere accentate da tastiera
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble} % Preambolo classicthesis
\usepackage{classicthesis}      % Classicthesis

\begin{document}

\input{Chapters/0_Introduction}
[...]

\end{document}
```

I would like to avoid this little issue.

I use TeXworks in Windows7 x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `classicthesis-preamble.sty` includes these lines:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,drafting,listings,%linedheaders,%pdfspacing,%listings,
                                            subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}
```

so this package internally passes the `drafting` option to `classicthesis`. If you want to avoid this, you can 1) Not load the `classicthesis-preamble` package or 2) Change the order in which the packages are loaded:

```
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
```

I don't know, however, what side effects could this last option produce.

3) Make a copy of `classicthesis-preamble.sty` and save it as `myclassicthesis-preamble.sty` somewhere TeX can find it (your current working directory, for example). Open this file and search for the lines I mentioned above and comment-out (or delete) the `drafting` option. Save this file, and in your document, instead of

```
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
```

use

```
\usepackage{myclassicthesis-preamble}
```

Comment: To resolve the side effect (this warning: `Package "classicthesis" should be loaded AFTER "classicthesis-preamble"`) I have now adopted the _3rd_ solution.